# Different Symbols Different Colours

Tags: symbols, color, tikzsymbols

I have a lot of data points that have been plotted in graphs saved as .png. I am making a table of these points with symbol as one of the columns. I need to have a red dot inscribed in a blue circle and inscribing a times in it. This has to be in the column. 
How do I go about doing this?

Using the tikz package, I have been able to create the red dot inscribed in the blue circle but I am unable to over lay an 'x' on it.

Basically is should be a \currency with a dot at the center. I should be able to define the colours for the dot, circle and the x.

The code for the the red dot inscribed in the blue circle is as follows.

```
  \usepackage{tikz}

 \newcommand{\bluereddot}[1][0.3]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
 \draw[fill=red,red] (0,0) circle (0.15);
 \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (0.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bluereddot}[1][0.3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \draw[fill=red,red] (0,0) circle (0.15);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (0.4);
    \draw[blue] (-135:0.6) -- (45:0.6) (135:0.6) -- (-45:0.6);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Is this the symbol \bluereddot{} you are looking for?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: caverac : yes. It is something like this only that the 'x' extends out side the circle.

Comment: @Bryan How about now?